# Android copy other apps assets file from your app on rooted device

Tags: android, assets, android-context

I have multiple apps on my device which are developed by myself. I want to copy other apps assets file to sdcard locally with current new app which I am working on, so that I don't need to upload same set of files on all of my app assets directory. My device is rooted and I can add shared key in manifest.xml too. 
Do anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean with `other apps` ?

Comment: Example - I have two apps A and B. A as few assets files and few times in app B i have to copy same asset files from A to sdcard locally. I know how to copy from app A to sdcard but I don't know on how to copy app A assets files from App B to sdcard.

Comment: If they are both your apps then B could 'ask' A to copy the assets files to a certain destination. B could start A using an intent with a destination parameter (use putExtra). You don't need a rooted device for that. So good for general use.

Comment: Could you write down the intent syntax for me please? I want to access AssestManager of app A from App B so I need context to access.

Comment: No you did understand me wrong. B has no access to A's assets. B can only ask A to do the work. It is just that Activity B starts Activity A.